# Why require permanent pens and disallow correction tools in exams?

Tags: exams, cheating

A common rule in exams is to require them being written with permanent (non-erasable) pens, which includes usually ballpoint pens and fountain pens filled with special ink. The rule forbids using fountain pens with erasable ink, ink erasers, pencils, correction tape, or fluid.

What is the point of such a rule?

*I’ll give my answer according to my own research and understanding below, but I am interested in anything that adds to it or refutes it.*

Comment: I don't believe I have actually seen this restriction, at all levels ...

Comment: Kind of bizarre to see this question. Is this a question anyone ever asked? Is it not obvious it's to prevent altering the marks after the fact?

Comment: @user541686: It is not obvious to some of my students for sure. Since I could not really find a comprehensive resource on this, I thought I might as well create one.

Comment: @Allure Anecdotally, this restriction was in place for every single (non-digital) written exam I’ve ever taken in my life, from elementary school all the way up through university.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Really? I don't think I ever took an exam where I was required to write with pen. Indeed, for many exams I was required to use a pencil to accommodate ancient automatic scanners that relied on the reflectivity of pencil marks and would report an exam with answers written in pen as blank.

Comment: @A.R. Interesting. I’ve never even heard of exam papers being processed by automatic scanners. Ours would just be copied on regular photocopiers and kept in school archives (nowadays they are presumably scanned and stored on servers). I don’t immediately see the benefit, either – how much can you automate about a five-page handwritten essay? The only situation where I can really see it being useful would be for multiple-choice, and those don’t exist on exams here. There is of course a trope that US exams are all multiple-choice … might that reflect your experience?

Comment: "A common rule in exams is to require them being written with permanent (non-erasable) pens" - Is it? I'm currently attending classes at a university in the US and all of my professors require my tests be taken with erasable pencils. Is this more common in other countries, perhaps?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure how seriously the trope you mentioned is considered, but in my last four semesters as a full time student in a US university, I've had zero multiple choice tests.

Comment: @Todd For college-level education, I’ve always assumed it’s just a meme. I get the impression that there may be more truth to it in regards to elementary and high school, but I’ve never studied in the US, so I have zero first-hand knowledge.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's been a long time, but in my memory I used pencil in elementary school. Come high school, pens became expected but correction fluid was not banned. I understood it as pencil fades much easier than pens, which makes pencil exams harder to grade. I also remember MCQs where you shade the answer for grading (not necessarily with machines, teachers used paper cutouts to grade this too). The instructions would specifically say to use a 2B or HB pencil.

Answer (score 19):

I see three reasons for this (roughly sorted by relevance):

- The forbidden tools increase the opportunities for the student to tamper with the exam when they get to review it and remark marking mistakes.¹
  While examiners can make a point by completely ignoring anything using forbidden tools, this would be disproportionately strict and also just creates extra work for the examiners.
  However, examiners have good reason to refuse to correct their markings on an exam or part thereof where forbidden tools were used.
- Most, if not all of the forbidden tools are more susceptible to accidental damage:
  Non-permanent ink dissolves better, correction tape can be rubbed off, some correctable ink is susceptible to light and temperature, etc.
  Should any of these things happen and not using forbidden tool could have avoided the loss or distortion of answers, the examiner can more easily (and often justifiably) refuse any claims based on this.
  For example, anybody can claim that correction tape with relevant content written on top somehow rubbed off during the correction of the exam.
- It is more difficult for the correctors to tamper with the exam and thus it is more difficult for the student to demonstrate that this happened.
  (Thanks to [Federico Poloni](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/958/federico-poloni) for adding this point.)

So, from the examiner’s point of view, students use the the forbidden tools at their own risk.

---

¹ Of course, it is never possible to fully exclude that somebody improves their solution by simply adding something, but such things can only be done with suitable mistakes and corrections. For example, a student may fix a mistake by changing “*x*” to “*x*²”, but only if the latter happens to be correct and the correction wasn’t adding a “²” in red (or whatever colour is used for correction). On top, the exam review should be surveilled to spot if anybody is writing in their exams.

Comment: I agree with your reasons. People put another reason in -- I'm not in favour of it though: You see the student's thought process if you force them to cross rather than correct. For me, the first is #1 reason and when I got a pencil-written exam in, I made a copy and stapled it to the original.

Comment: @yo': *when I got a pencil-written exam in, I made a copy and stapled it to the original.* – If some rule required me to copy every exam using pencil or similar, I would instantiate a rule that I do not even look at any such exam, just to avoid that work.

Comment: You are missing a third reason: it makes it harder *for the teacher* to tamper with the exam.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Indeed, although hopefully much less relevant than the other two reasons. I added this.

Comment: As @yo' said, you see the student's thought process. This can be useful if there is a suspicion of cheating

Comment: @toby544: While this may provide some counter-evidence against cheating, I would not rely to much on it. Some students prefer to perform the thought process mostly in their heads and they should certainly not be punished for that.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Why would a teacher tamper an exam? Why would anyone want to study in such a place where this happens? Yes, I know exams might be bought, but seriously, there are ways to do this that are far easier to hide. If you don't trust the teachers in absence of strong evidence to the contrary, you can as well do away with the process of assessments.

Comment: "*exclude that somebody improves their solution by simply adding something*" - we had exams where TAs were encouraged to cross out any space left free during correction (just a swipe across the page), to make it easier to detect such tampering. It was a large class and students were allowed to write during review, on separate sheets for their remarks or personal note-taking.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs In normal conditions teachers don't tamper with exams, I agree. Still, it makes sense that a university has rules in place to ensure everyone plays fair.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs In my youth admission to the elite secondary school was by examination ("the qualifying exam"). Teachers at some schools were said to improve the papers of their own pupils so as to enhance their own reputations.

Comment: @erstwhileeditor Ok, that's a good example. It is a tricky one to prevent. One reason "grading on the curve" is tolerated is because it acts as countermeasure to this. However, it comes with its own set of unfairness.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs It's one of the case studies from Freakonomics. Regardless of how often it actually happens, pop science has made people believe it's a real phenomenon.

Comment: @fectin Which one is the real phenomenon, improving one's students' results or grading to the curve? Or both?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs improving student's results.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow your first point. When exactly would the student sitting the exam have the opportunity to tamper with anything? Perhaps I’m misunderstanding how the exam you’re describing works, but in all written exams I’ve sat where restrictions like these were in place, the student hands in the paper when the time (usually four or five hours) is up, and then never sees it again until after it has been graded, at which point the school has archived a copy. Tampering with it at this point would be pointless. Your second point was the only reason ever given to us.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: *never sees it again until after it has been graded, at which point the school has archived a copy* – Here, we have a designated event where students get to see their exam again (under surveillance, without pens and similar). Then the original exams get archived. We do not make copies of the exam, because it would not be worth the major effort.

Comment: We usually got to take our graded exams home and keep them (the copies were then stored in the school archives – I imagine they’re probably scanned and stored on a server nowadays), but that’s a minor difference that doesn’t really affect the overall process much. I just don’t see, even in your system, when and why the _student_ would/could ever tamper with the paper. At the event you describe, they’d be hard pressed to because of the surveillance – and besides, it’s already been graded at that point, right? So what would be the purpose of tampering with it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: One purpose of the event is that the students get to remonstrate grading mistakes, so there is some incentive to tamper with the exam. While surveillance and the prohibition of pens also serve to prevent tampering, forbidding correction tools in the exam adds another layer of security here. None of these measures is very good on its own, but taken together they are.

Answer (score 12):

The [answer by Wrzlprmft](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/207995/63475) focuses on exam integrity reasons for this instruction. I'm more familiar with an academic system in the US that does not treat most exams quite as seriously as is common in Europe, so while I think everything in this answer is accurate I've also heard reasons related to the type of work expected and practical issues with erasing.

If the instructor is expecting a stream-of-consciousness sort of answer and not an edited manuscript, they do not want students to go back over and erase and edit their work because this will cost them time "improving" things that don't matter for the grade at the cost of time not spent on those that do.

Practically, erasers (particularly for pencil) often do not work well and it can take substantial effort to erase and the results may not be legible. A simple strike through and re-write in ink, if necessary, takes less time and is more legible anyways.

Comment: I don't find this argument very convincing. Surely, part of education is also that the student learns in which situations to be cautious about cosmetic details of the written text, and in which to avoid wasting time on this! Regarding erasers specifically, they can send vibrations through a whole row of tables, distracting other examinees, so there's that at least...

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are a range of views on those sorts of "meta instruction" goals; many educators would say "my job is to teach Physics, therefore my assessments should be strictly on students' knowledge of Physics" and anything else is noise. In that context, the instructor wants students to focus on specifically what they are being assessed on rather than testing whether they know to avoid cosmetic details when not necessary. It can be painful to see a student who knows the material perform poorly on a test for reasons not relevant to the course content.

Comment: "does not treat most exams quite as seriously as is common in Europe" [citation needed]

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Maybe "formally" would have been a better choice of word. And, yes, it's probably a mistake to ever say "Europe" as if it refers to one place.

Comment: @BryanKrause Actually, I thought exams are treated much more formal in the Anglo-Saxon realm, than, say, Germany. Sure, there is invigilation etc. but I found it far less impositional in terms of hard external parameters.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs The US does not do anything like the UK with exams; not sure who all you're counting as Anglo-Saxons which I believe best describes a cultural group who haven't existed (that is, are better described culturally using other terms) for 1000 years. In the US in most cases there is no exam board, no protocol, no one responsible except the instructor for the course. Some bureaucracy may be invented to try to make things equal among different course sections when they exist, but that's about it. Grades may or may not even depend heavily on exams, and the final may not be important.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ok, I take it back. Then the US is like Germany (at least as it was 20 or so years ago).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Germany twenty years ago is a muddy reference point. It was in the middle of implementing the Bologna reforms, which in particular affected exams quite a lot.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Fair enough. Just before Bologna. I do not know details about how it looked afterwards, as I had left by then.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to concerns about cheating, I think there are more mundane practical concerns:

- Correction fluid can create a mess, including melting/sticking pages together/getting ripped off.

(I think correction tape may suffer from similar problems but to a lesser extent.)

On Cambridge International exams ([example](http://web.archive.org/web/20240226031158/https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/images/233966-2015-paper-3-specimen-paper.pdf)), the instructions contain this line: *Do not use staples, paper clips, glue or correction fluid.*

Putting correction fluid together with staples, paper clips, and glue strongly suggests the concern is less about cheating and more about the above practical concern.

- Pens are often clearer than pencils

Also from the Cambridge International exam instructions: *Write in dark blue or black pen.*

We know markers use red pens. But the above also specifically prohibits pens of any other colors (e.g. light blue/pink/purple/green), suggesting there is a desire for exam-takers' writing to be clearly legible.

Also, nowadays, exam scripts are sometimes scanned (where again any writing in pencil might be less clear than writing in dark blue/black pens).

- Some teachers/schools/academic systems treat any writing in pencil as the student's own rough work for herself that will be ignored and won't be marked

Comment: Green pen is sometimes used if there's a 2nd marker - and that accounts for all the common colours when the rules originated.  Now you can get any colour you like, it's still clearer to stick with blues and blacks for work to be marked.  I have seen professional exams being marked on photocopies - blue and black copy well unlike some colours (at least in the past)

Comment: I occasionally had to use a different colour than red to mark an exam, because the student wrote their exam in multiple colours of pen, including red. When this happened I would make a note on the front of the script explaining what colour I had marked in and why. So the requirement that students write in blue or black is not just for legibility, it also allows markings made by different authors to be differentiated.

Answer (score 4):

All our exams (a Norwegian university) that's still conducted on paper are done on triplicate carbon copy paper.
This means that erasing isn't possible, so using erasable tools are just asking for trouble if the student try to erase anything (or use correction tools like tape or fluid).
And ballpoint pens work better for getting a proper copy on all three layers than pencils do.

Comment: That's an interesting fact - do the students get to take a copy? Or does everything get processed with in the system?

Comment: @Joe: 1 copy for the student which they get immediately, 2 copies for the institution, usually intended so both the internal and external examiner can get a copy each. Then, after correcting, 1 copy is stored in the archives (the top form in the triplicate, the one the student actually wrote on)

Comment: that's super interesting, I'll be telling my students that immediately.